# How to swap two strings in file using bash?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, swap

I have a file with:

```
q12 q25 
q13 q15
q78 q13
q42 q54
q13 q12
q12 q74
q45 q25
```

I want to replace any `12 to 13` and any `13 to 12` :

```
q13 q25 
q12 q15
q78 q12
q42 q54
q12 q13
q13 q74
q45 q25
```

how to do this with a simple command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `perl` you could avoid making use of a placeholder string to perform the substitutions.

Create a hash of the transformations that are needed and perform a substitution:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{%h=("12" => "13", "13" => "12")} s/(12|13)/$h{$1}/g' inputfile
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
q13 q25
q12 q15
q78 q12
q42 q54
q12 q13
q13 q74
q45 q25
```

Use the `-i` option to save the changes to the file in-place.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like :

```
sed "s/13/tmp/g;s/12/13/g;s/tmp/12/g" file
```

You could use `-i` option if you want to replace inside the file :

```
sed -i "s/13/tmp/g;s/12/13/g;s/tmp/12/g" file
```

Comment: and be sure that there's no legit `tmp` in file. Also if you want to do it in place (from and to `file`), use the `-i` argument of sed.

Comment: @zmo I've edited my answer in the same time ^^ (for the `-i` option).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
perl -i.bak -ne '/12/ && !/13/ && s/12/13/g && print; /13/ && !/12/ && s/13/12/g && print; !/12/ && !/13/ && print ' file; cat file
q13 q25 
q12 q25 
q12 q15
q78 q12
q42 q54
q13 q74
q12 q74
q45 q25
```